# How to get rid of popup "Please select a valid value. The two nearest valid values are..." on form input after javascript calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple form that asks for the price of a container of items and then also another input for the number of items in the container.  The javascript simply divides the total number of individual items into the price to get a "per unit" cost.  The script works, but every time I run it, it pops up a notification on the price input box "Please select a valid value.  The two nearest valid values are..." because the price input is a decimal.

If I edit the input line in the HTML for price and add "step="0.01", then the script doesn't output anything.

Oddly, I added "step="any"" to the output box and it works as I was getting the same popup on the output box as well.  I absolutely want the large decimal places in the unit cost output.

Here's the HTML (it is styled using CSS Grid so everything is positioned the way I want it):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Unit Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contain">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Unit Cost Calculator</h3>

      <form id="unitCost" action="">
        <p>
          <label for="itemdesc">Item Description</label>
          <input id="itemdesc" name="itemdesc" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input id="price" name="price" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="quantity">Qty.</label>
          <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="unit">Unit Cost</label>
          <input id="unit" name="unit" type="number" step="any" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="singleUnitCost">Single Unit Cost</label>
          <input id="singleUnitCost" name="singleUnitCost" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="subm"></label>
          <input type="submit" value="Calculate Per Unit Cost" onclick="units()" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="rest"></label>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>

function units() {
   var pric=document.getElementById('price').value;
   var qty=document.getElementById('quantity').value;
   var result=document.getElementById('unit');
   var myResult=pric/qty;
     document.getElementById('unit').value=myResult;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in the script, I want to take the price, multiply it by 0.06 (this is the 6% sales tax rate), add the price back to it so I actually get the price after tax has been added, but when I do that math on the "myResult" line of code like:

```
var myResult=(pric*0.06+pric)/qty;
```

Then the script doesn't work at all.

Ugh.  I'm learning really quick that javascript math and forms is frustrating.

Comment: try var myResult = Math.floor((pric*0.06+pric)/qty);

Comment: When I add that, I get a pop up that says to please input a valid number on the price box.  I edited the HTML portion to set that field input to number and step=0.01.  Then the script does not work at all (when I click the calculate button, nothing happens).

Comment: i try to run your html and js but it doesn't show me any alert. can u make a jsfiddle

Comment: It is now working as desired due to vgf's input below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main error is that you are trying to use the `value`s directly as numbers. If you set them as actual numbers, things work as expected. Usually, you want the price with two decimal positions:

```js
function units() {
   var pric=Number(document.getElementById('price').value);
   var qty=Number(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
   var result=document.getElementById('unit');
  debugger;
   var myResult=(pric*0.06+pric)/qty;
     document.getElementById('unit').value=myResult;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Unit Cost Calculator</h3>

      <form id="unitCost" action="javascript:void(0);">
        <p>
          <label for="itemdesc">Item Description</label>
          <input id="itemdesc" name="itemdesc" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input id="price" name="price" type="number" step="0.01"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="quantity">Qty.</label>
          <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="unit">Unit Cost</label>
          <input id="unit" name="unit" type="number" step="any" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="singleUnitCost">Single Unit Cost</label>
          <input id="singleUnitCost" name="singleUnitCost" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="subm"></label>
          <input type="submit" value="Calculate Per Unit Cost" onclick="units()" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="rest"></label>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main change is that `pric` and `qty` are inside the `Number` function. Also, please notice that the `action` of the form is `javascript:void(0);` so that nothing is sent. You would need to change that back in your example.

Comment: Changed code as you have above, (and changed the form action back) and it doesn't work.  When I click "calculate" button, it just clears the price and quantity fields of the numbers I typed into them and outputs nothing.

Comment: Disregard, I got it working, I change the action to the page itself and now it works!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, you may want to accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, I did.  Thanks again.